# Apollo Type generator (codegen:generate) with multiple endpoints

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

Trying to find a way to generate types for my GraphQl operations with different endpoint URIs.

We have an endpoint for user authentication and one for everything else and therefore we also need two different Apollo clients.

However we are using them both in one Vuex actions file and we are running into a problem when generating types for these operations, because we can only define one endpoint in the Apollo `codegen:generate` command, like this:
`apollo codegen:generate --target typescript --excludes=node_modules/* --includes=./src/**/*.ts --endpoint https://oneOfOurEndpoints  --tagName=gql --outputFlat src/models`.

Is there a way to go through multiple endpoints without the need to separate the GraphQl operations into separate files and running two different `codegen:generate` commands?

Comment: Were you able to figure out the answer to this?

Comment: Had to separate them into multiple files then import them back into the actions file and add to the actions object. @hayreenfly

Comment: @Jousi can you share the script/code snippet, please?